number of permutations without stable element
I know the number of permutation is $n!$ and number of permutation without stable point is $$!n = n!\sum_{k=0}^n(−1)^k/k!$$
Is it known the number of permutation pairs $(p,p')$ such that $p(i) \neq p'(i)$ for all $i$?
Thanks

Let's fix some terminology. We call such a pair $(p, p')$ as in your question a nice pair.
Note that $(1, p)$ is a nice pair if and only if $p$ is a derangement, i.e. has no stable points. There are $!n$ such pairs.
Here's an easy lemma:
Lemma. If $(p, p')$ is a nice pair then so is $(qp,qp')$ for any $q \in S_n$.
I will leave the proof as an exercise.
Given $p, p' \in S_n$, we have that $(p, p')$ is nice if and only if $(1, p^{-1}p')$ is nice. It follows quickly that every nice pair $(p, p')$ is obtained by taking an arbitrary permutation $p$, a derangement $q$, and letting $p' = pq$.
Thus, there are $n! \times !n$ nice (ordered) pairs. If you would like unordered pairs, then simply divide by two.

Thanks for clear explanation. I phrased the question inaccurately. I'm wondering if there's a known number of derangement pairs (p,p′) such that p(i)≠p′(i) for all i?
